# Writing a $.cookie to show a form upon submit in a multi form page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, form-submit

Writing a page with use of $.cookie to show a form upon submit in a multi form page.  I have seen similar questions go unanswered when it got to this specific code. I have read and read, seems like this should work. Yes, very new to jquery, 1 week.

I have container divs (class) each with an p toggle to show/hide each form.  Upon submit I want the form to remain .show() so that errors or even response will be seen.  p must be clicked to .hide form; so a person could open all the forms.

I know there are much more complicated ways to do this.  I just want to learn the simple, possibly long hand version so help me understand what is going on. I added a number of alerts for hints.  Some reason loops back to undefined.

Sorry I am so 'green'.  I am sure this is too simple for most here.

css:

```
.set {
     }
.set form {
display: none;
   }
.set p {
    color: #996600;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.set p.hover {
background-color: #00CCCC;
    }
```

the html:

```
<div class="set"><p>Click</p>
<form id="form1">

 <div id="here" style="text-align:center; border:1px solid black; width:60px;">form 1</div>
   <button id="form1button" class="button">BUTTON form1</button>

</form>
</div>


<div class="set"><p>Click2</p>
<form id="form2" >

<div id="here" style="text-align:center; border:1px solid black;  width:60px;">Click</div>
    <button id="form2button" class="button">BUTTON form2</button>
</form>
</div>


<div class="set"><p>Click3</p>
    <form id="form3" >

<div id="here" style="text-align:center; border:1px solid black;  width:60px;">Click</div>
<button id="form3button" class="button">BUTTON form3</button>
</form>
</div>
```

the jquery:

```
if($.cookie('toogle')=== undefined) {
$('.set form#form1').show();
alert('undefined');


if ($.cookie('toogle') == 'form1') {
    $('.set form#form1').show();
    $('.set form#form2').hide();
    $('.set form#form3').hide();
} else if ($.cookie('toogle') == 'form2') {
    $('.set form#form2').show();
    $('.set form#form1').hide();
    $('.set form#form3').hide();
} else if ($.cookie('toogle') == 'form3') {
    $('.set form#form3').show();
    $('.set form#form1').hide();
    $('.set form#form2').hide();
} else {
    $('.set form#form1').show();
    $('.set form#form2').hide();
    $('.set form#form3').hide();    
};

alert($.cookie('toggle'));

    $('#form1button').on('click', function() {

        $.cookie('toggle', 'form1');
            alert('form1 button!!!');
    });

    $('#form2button').on('click', function() {

        $.cookie('toggle', 'form2');
            alert('form2 button!!!');
    });

    $('#form3button').on('click', function() {

        $.cookie('toggle', 'form3');
            alert('form3 button!!!');
    }); 

$('.set p').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('slow');

    });
```

Comment: Would you mind setting up a fiddle? Also, in simple terms, what is your goal?

Comment: Also, if this is only required on the current page, why use cookies?

Comment: I will go with anything that works,..:) I am not crazy about counting on cookies anyway.

Comment: This page is multiple forms.  Instead of one after the other in long list I just want Change Password, Add/Edit address, Add/edit phone.  Click, and form slides down. But once the submit button is clicked the div collapses back to .hide; hard to validate a form when it goes away. I have more experience in PHP.  This is my first attempt in Jquery. fiddle,.ok.  will post link.

Comment: Ok gotcha, definitely use ajax, keep your php processing page intact and we will use the ajax call to push the form info to your php page, then the php will output the results and kick back to success handler in the ajax call. I'll wait to see your fiddle so I can at least see how the hide show actions are set up.

Comment: Ok bro...I came up with a simple setup for you. I am going to post the scripts and a like to an example. I explained most of it in comments on the script...let me know of any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so overall we will have a page with the forms, and a php processing page. I explained most of it in the comments. Let me know if you have any questions!

[Here is a demonstration page](http://videsignz.com/stackoverflow/send-ajax-form)

This is a quick validation to see if the value is empty or not, you can do whatever validating you need to

Page 1 - send-ajax-form.php - CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">
     button.close {display:none;}
     form {display:none;}
     .form-wrapper {margin:10px; padding:10px; background-color:#E8E8E8;}
     .error {color:red;}
     .success {color:green;}
 </style>
```

Page 1 - send-ajax-form.php - HTML

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div>Form One</div>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="formval" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div id="form1status"></div>
    </form>    
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div>Form Two</div>
    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" name="formval" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div id="form2status"></div>
    </form>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div>Form Three</div>
    <form id="form3">
        <input type="text" name="formval" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div id="form3status"></div>
    </form>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

Page 1 - send-ajax-form.php - Script (Buttons)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    // Edit and Close Button Functions

    $('body').on('click', '.edit', function(){
        $(this).hide().siblings('.close').show().siblings('form').slideDown();
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
        $(this).hide().siblings('.edit').show().siblings('form').slideUp();
    });

</script>
```

Page 1 - send-ajax-form.php - Script (Ajax Calls)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Each form will have its own ajax call, all posted to the same php page.

    // Form 1   
    $('#form1').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // Stop regular form submission     

        var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); // This works around IE caching, as you see, I attach it to the end of the post below

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Obviously we are posting to the php page.
            url: "process-ajax-form.php", //the php page to post to.
            cache: false, // This is needed to prevent caching, the random number from above will reinforce this as well.
                  // Serialize the form data, then add the formname key/value so php knows which form is coming over.
            data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&formname=form1&random=" + randnum, // random number at the end for no-caching.
            dataType: "html", // I am using html here, so it will expect html to be spit back from the php processing page.
                              //You could use other data types as well just make sure the php echos that type of data.
            timeout: 5000, // This will through an error after 5 seconds if it cannot connect with the server
            error: function(){
                // Show some server error message somehow (This has nothing to do with your php proccessing page)
            },
            success: function(response){ // Variable 'response' will hold the html that comes back from the php echos
                // Success means something was received back from the php page (No matter if your php outputs succes or error)
                // So lets do something with the results!!!!
                $('#form1status').html('').html(response);  // Clear current status message then insert PHP results         
            }

        }); 

    });

    // Form 2   
    $('#form2').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // Stop regular form submission     

        var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); // This works around IE caching, as you see, I attach it to the end of the post below

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Obviously we are posting to the php page.
            url: "process-ajax-form.php", //the php page to post to.
            cache: false, // This is needed to prevent caching, the random number from above will reinforce this as well.
                  // Serialize the form data, then add the formname key/value so php knows which form is coming over.
            data: $('#form2').serialize() + "&formname=form2&random=" + randnum, // random number at the end for no-caching.
            dataType: "html", // I am using html here, so it will expect html to be spit back from the php processing page.
                              //You could use other data types as well just make sure the php echos that type of data.
            timeout: 5000, // This will through an error after 5 seconds if it cannot connect with the server
            error: function(){
                // Show some server error message somehow (This has nothing to do with your php proccessing page)
            },
            success: function(response){ // Variable 'response' will hold the html that comes back from the php echos
                // Success means something was received back from the php page (No matter if your php outputs succes or error)
                // So lets do something with the results!!!!
                $('#form2status').html('').html(response);  // Clear current status message then insert PHP results         
            }

        }); 

    });

    // Form 3   
    $('#form3').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // Stop regular form submission     

        var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); // This works around IE caching, as you see, I attach it to the end of the post below

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Obviously we are posting to the php page.
            url: "process-ajax-form.php", //the php page to post to.
            cache: false, // This is needed to prevent caching, the random number from above will reinforce this as well.
                  // Serialize the form data, then add the formname key/value so php knows which form is coming over.
            data: $('#form3').serialize() + "&formname=form3&random=" + randnum, // random number at the end for no-caching.
            dataType: "html", // I am using html here, so it will expect html to be spit back from the php processing page.
                              //You could use other data types as well just make sure the php echos that type of data.
            timeout: 5000, // This will through an error after 5 seconds if it cannot connect with the server
            error: function(){
                // Show some server error message somehow (This has nothing to do with your php proccessing page)
            },
            success: function(response){ // Variable 'response' will hold the html that comes back from the php echos
                // Success means something was received back from the php page (No matter if your php outputs succes or error)
                // So lets do something with the results!!!!
                $('#form3status').html('').html(response);  // Clear current status message then insert PHP results         
            }

        }); 

    });

</script>
```

Page 2 - process-ajax-form.php - PHP

```
<!-- For each form on the page, set up your validation -->
<!-- Here I am doing a simple validation to see if the form value is empty or not -->

<?php

 //Check if its form 1
if($_POST['formname']==='form1'){

    $formval = $_POST['formval']; //Put value posted into variable

        // Validate however you would like
        if($formval===""){
            echo "<span class='error'>Uh oh, something went wrong with form 1!</span>";
        }else{
            echo "<span class='success'>Great, everything is all good with form 1!</span>";
        }
}

?>

 <?php

 //Check if its form 2
if($_POST['formname']==='form2'){

    $formval = $_POST['formval']; //Put value posted into variable

        // Validate however you would like
        if($formval===""){
            echo "<span class='error'>Uh oh, something went wrong with form 2!</span>";
        }else{
            echo "<span class='success'>Great, everything is all good with form 2!</span>";
        }
}

?>

    <?php

 //Check if its form 3
if($_POST['formname']==='form3'){

    $formval = $_POST['formval']; //Put value posted into variable

        // Validate however you would like
        if($formval===""){
            echo "<span class='error'>Uh oh, something went wrong with form 3!</span>";
        }else{
            echo "<span class='success'>Great, everything is all good with form 3!</span>";
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: WOW!  I need to digest but I really appreciate the method.  Very readable!!

Comment: @Cloverlone Did you check out the demo page?

Comment: I don't have ajax exp yet but I follow. It is not working for me BUT I am on an old firefox... helps me keep code written for older versions in case such event occurs. I expect if I get the latest version it will work BUT what is cut off for browser versions? Is it worth worrying about? or am I being silly?

Comment: @Cloverlone Hmmm...there should not be a reason it's not working, jquery is super cross browser compatible.  Its working for me on FF, IE and Safari. What version are you running?

Comment: @Cloverlone what version are you running? I'm on version 26

Comment: Really embarrassed, but I have an old machine still running windows XP so on 3.6.25. Always believed in  coding for oldest first but obviously Jquery has limited abilities on old browsers.  .parent, .child would be my first guess. When I went to do a fiddle none of the fields show text as I typed, all blank! Same for drop downs, blank.  I can go see examples but can't use the form. Shopping.

Comment: not parent child, i meant siblings.  i will try a small .sibling code and see if it works in this browser.  Been challenging to figure out what is browser and what is my mistake.  I soooo appreciate what you wrote.  It makes sense to me :)

Comment: @Cloverlone Hey man, don't be embarrased... check out these links.  Some good stats on browsers and versions. This is for all browsers (You can click a specific browser for specififc stats)  http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp and this is for FF specifically http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp

Comment: So, I have been breaking this down to find why my browser won't do this.  I actually had it work ONCE when I added an alert before and after the show sibling; could not duplicate. I finally figured that it would not even do a basic 'form'.show().  I added an internal wrapper to just the form, and made it display:none instead of form and now it works.  Still messing with it to be sure.  We have had storm weather.  I am a 'farmer' so sorry its been a week.

Comment: so the hide/show works with my innerwrap BUT when I press submit, the form disappears - no PHP 'all went well', 'errors',..etc show up since wrapper does not stay open. ugh,.. Been at this so long I almost forgot what I was trying to accomplish.