# jquery/ajax is there a better way to post this data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok currently I'm creating a list that is generated from a database with the format below.

```
    echo '<ul id="sortable" class="mainlist">';
    echo '<div class="listwrap" id="arrange_'.$listid.'"><li><span class="item1"><a       class="checkmarked"               href="check.php?id1='.$newlistid.'">'.$value.'</a></span>
<span class="item2">&#x25B2; | &#x25BC;</span>
<span class="item3">'.$list.'</span>
<span class="item4">'.$description.'</span>
<span class="item5">'.$date.'</span>
<span class="item6"><a class="confirm" href="deletelist.php?id1='.$newlistid.'">&#x2717;</a></span></li></div>';
   echo '</ul>';
```

The spans with the class item1 and with class item6 I'm using urls to pass the (encrypted) id of the list to a seperate php site that gets the results and plugs them into a database.  It then uses javascript to redirect the user back to the original site so that you can see the changes.  This takes a small amount of time however and briefly blanks out the page while the script is working.  Is it possible to do this same functionality with some sort of jquery/ jquery ajax call to the script page?  My main concerns are that the id must be the one that I'm clicking on so that I'm not deleting or modifying other content.  Anyway, Thanks in advance for the help!

edit----

here is the script that catches the data

```
    $oldlistid = $_GET['id1'];
```

... some decryption stuff to make it $listid

```
$checkdb = $db->prepare('SELECT checkbox FROM list_simple WHERE LIST_ID=?');
$checkdb->execute(array($listid));
$row = $checkdb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE list_simple SET checkbox=? WHERE LIST_ID=?');
    if ($row['checkbox']) {

        $check = 0;
        $stmt->execute(array($check, $listid));
        echo '<script>window.location.replace("/ToDoneList/ToDoneList/usr/usr.php");</script>';
    }
    else {
        $check = 1;
        $stmt->execute(array($check, $listid)); 
        echo '<script>window.location.replace("/ToDoneList/ToDoneList/usr/usr.php");</script>';
    }



?>
```

Comment: What JS code do you have right now? Show us, please.

Comment: You can use the `li` as the block-level element instead of the `div`, especially since using a `div` inside the `ul` directly isn't valid structure.

Comment: I don't really have any related javascript code for this, the only javascript I'm using is to redirect back to the main page.  I've read a little about $.post but I don't know if there is a way I can pass that information without it always being the last element in the list that is passed because the variable will be changed by the time the script runs

Comment: Check this link...see my answer, its a good start for you possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615605/writing-a-cookie-to-show-a-form-upon-submit-in-a-multi-form-page/21634555#21634555