# Use php to validate a html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to validate a html form using php. I have solved it in one like below:

Part of my html form:

```
  <input class="text" type="text" name="fname" id="firstname1"  required="required">
```

And at the `signup.php` I have

```
<?php

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['fname']))
  {
  echo ('Name should include only characters'); 
  die( '</body></html>' );
  } 
  ?>
```

But my problem is that in this form the error message does not appear at the same page with the form, but in another page. I want to have the error message appear at the page where the form is.

In javascript I make it this way, but I don't know how to make this in php:
I build a function like below:

```
function name() {

    var pass = document.getElementById('firstname1');
    var sb = document.getElementById('submit1');
    var letters=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (pass.value.match(letters) ){
     sb.disabled = false;
     document.getElementById('error-fname1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    else {
         document.getElementById('error-fname1').style.display = 'block';
        sb.disabled = true;  }
          }
```

and then I try to call it in this way:

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="fname" id="firstname1"  required="required" onchange="name()">

<span class="errorformat "  id="error-fname1"  style="display: none" >
          Please write only letters
                    </span>
```

Please help me...I am trying to learn php... Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you setting the `action` of the form to another page?  If so, the only way you could put an error message on the old page with the **server-side** PHP code is by redirecting back to the old page.

Comment: yes when I press submit button i go to another page that said: succesor output the error message. This page is called signup.php and there I also connect the form with the database and there i chack for errors. But how can I check for errors in the page where i have the form so in signup.html page?

Comment: How can I redirect back the old page?

Comment: You can't simply check on the same page using PHP.  The whole point of PHP is that it is a **sever-side** code.

Comment: You can do it using `AJAX` request, but you will need javascript and PHP.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Ajax.. So is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: without ajax, your PHP code that check for the submit errors have to be in the same page as your form (in the same file or include in the beginning).

Comment: yes I try to include it at the begining , but it does not function. Can I make a php function and call it whenever I want? What can I use in php instead of the javascript:  document.getElementById('error-fname1').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Check out my answer on this page, it is a simple setup for ajax/php validating and response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615605/writing-a-cookie-to-show-a-form-upon-submit-in-a-multi-form-page/21634555#21634555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you validate it on the same page.

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
  ... (Any checks you want to make)
}
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input class="text" type="text" name="fname" id="firstname1"  required="required">
</form>
```

That way, the php runs only if the form has been submitted, and the error will appear on the same page.

Comment: The form is meant to go to a different page, but the error message should be shown on the old page.

Comment: just redirect to the next page validation succeeded

Comment: Yes @Jaxon, what I have in mind is to make it in the same page with the form...I try to build a php function, and call it onchange...Because I want that when I click at the second input form and the first is not correct, to show the error...not to show the error at the end when I pres submit...But how can I do this?

Comment: You would need JavaScript for that but don't you already have a JavaScript validation?

Comment: Yes I have. But I was thinking which one to use. I am learning php now and I was thinking to make validation with php. But is is better in my case?

Comment: CAn i make both? Javascript to show error in the same page with the form and the php to make validation at the signup.php?

Comment: It would be best to use both since the JavaScript validation can be easily bypassed.  If you already have the JavaScript, you can look at my answer for PHP.

Comment: So it is not wrong if I use javascript to show errors in the form page and i use php to show errors in the other page not the old one?But I have one more question: If I use javascript and I validate my form with it, so I dont let the user go to submit page if an error exist, which is the function of php validation...because as i will not let the user go to submit page with error, the php validations will never catch errors....Or I am thinking wrong? Once more thanks a lot for your answer...

Comment: @user3272713 Anonymous is right, to be able to make a check with onchage, you have to use JavaScript. If you want it to validate on an onchange, my suggestion is that you call a JavaScript function when the input is changed, but also have the php validation later as a final check, since JavaScript checks are by-passable.

Comment: ok i undersatnd this....so it is no need to use php validation if i chack all with javascript?thanks a lot...

Comment: @user3272713 I still think you should have php validation after

Comment: ok thank a lot...I am a begginer and I that if it was wrong to make both....thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry out server side validation using php (which is highly recommended), then you can use the following approach by placing everything in the same file ... example file form.php

```
<?php

//validate form

if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['fname']))
{ 
$problem = true;
}
else
{
$formok = true;

?>
```

then the html part starts and you can at some point put your error message:

```
<?php if($problem) echo "Incorrect Name Format" ?>

<?php if($formok) echo "Nice job" ?>
```

then the form should be like this:

```
<form action="form.php">
//inputs
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a redirect to show the error message on the page before, you can do something similar to this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['fname'])) {
    header("Location: http://domain/oldpage.php");
    exit();
}
```

You could have it redirect to a new error page or possibly include a query string at the end of the link such as `?error=true`.  Then, check on the page for that query string and if it is there, display the error message.

Answer (score 0):

On the page where your form is at, add a GET var and check if it is set. Something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
   // Output error message logic here. Don't forget to sanitize the GET var //
}
```

In your file where you are handling the data, if you have any errors, header the user back to the page with your form with the error message attached.

```
$errormsg = '';
if($_POST['fname'] == trim("") || !isset($_POST['fname'])) {
  $errormsg = 'Please enter your name';
  header('location: signup.php?error='.$errormsg);
}
```

This assumes the page with your form is a PHP file. If it is not, just change the extension.